# Is there any way to block an specific product from Microsoft Update?

Tags: sql-server, wsus, windows-update

I have a scenario where an SQL Server update makes an app fail.

I would like to disable SQL Server updates.
I don't want to disable all other Updates. I would like to keep Windows Update.

Is there any way to do this?

These machines aren't in a domain and cannot use WSUS.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2008 R2, it fails with the update KB2494088

Comment: You know you can have non-domain machines use WSUS, right ?

Comment: If the OS is Server 2008 R2 why did you use the `windows-7` tag? Please ensure you use appropriate tags in future.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft/Windows Update gives you the ability to exclude specific updates from being offered / installed. Just opening the update notification window, unticking the update and selecting "Do not show this update again".

Of course, getting an update list in the WU notification dialog would require having the updates either set to "notify", hit the notification window before the updates are actually installed, or trigger the update detection manually through the WU client GUI.

Edit: There is no way to disable a specific product's updates, but you might choose to disable automatic updates for any Microsoft products apart from the OS itself by unticking this checkbox:

[image: Windows Update Settings]

Comment: And how could i  configure this for 10.000 machines? Any registry key? Any command? Thank you @syneticon-dj

Comment: @RicardoPolo You have 10,000 machines running SQL server? And you are not using SCCM or at least WSUS to deploy updates? For disabling MS update, consider trying the removal of the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Services\7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d key and restarting `wuauserv` - I have not tested it, but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826676(VS.85).aspx) suggests it might work out.

Comment: If you have 10K in machines or even 10 for that matter. Consider using and setting up Windows Update Service. Its included with server r2 for free. Pretty easy setup.